# how to add external file to maven package output jar during runtime?

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-2

I have a spring `maven` project. In that Project (root folder), I have folder called `config` which contains multiple folder like `t1`, `t2`, `t3` etc, Inside of each folder, I have `spring-config.xml` (config differs to each test environments)

while I package my project using `maven package`, I need `spring-config.xml` to be available in `classpath` of my output jar.

(I can do this by copying corresponding `config` file to `src/main/resources`), But I want all of my `config` files to be available in `root` directory, and maven should pick correct config file while packaging.

Is this possible to do while runtime(during maven command or by using any maven pluggins)

Note: To create `fat-jar` I'm using `maven-assembly-plugin`

```
<plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>first</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- ... -->
                            <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-${jarName}</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.main.MainClass</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the spring-boot-maven-plugin for packaging?

Comment: I think, I've solved by using <resources> by mentioning corresponding directory

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by using `<resources>`

```
<properties>
        <org.springframework.version>2.5.5</org.springframework.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

 <build>
        <finalName>myApp</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>config/${folderName}</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        //... pluggins
</build>
```

while execute `mvn` command I can pass folderName (`t1`,`t2`,`t3`..etc)

`mvn clean package -DfolderName=t1`
`mvn clean package -DfolderName=t2`.. etc

Now it is locating correct `file` based on my inputs.